# Access local web server using another public server

Tags: networking, webserver, reverse-tunnel

I have few web server running behind the NAT((accessible using local IP)), and I need to access the web server from public network. I cannot use port forwarding. Also I have a main central server which can be access from outside network. So is there any way these private web servers connect to the central webserver, and client can access it through the public server.

```
                        NAT
local Server1 -----------|-----------> |-----------------|
                         |             |                 | <----Client 1(To access Server1)
local Server2 -----------|-----------> |  Public Server  |
                         |             |                 | <----Client 2(To access Server2)
local Server3 -----------|---------->  |-----------------
```

I have already found VPN. But I cannot use it, I also found SSH revers tunnelling but cannot use  as there is latency. I have to stream video from each local server.

Is there any better solution to implement it.

Comment: I’d look into a Reverse Proxy solution, but you would still need a way to get the public server to access the web servers that are behind NAT. If you can’t use port forwarding, a VPN (or SSH tunnel) would be the most appropriate. You’ve not explained why you cannot use a VPN. Also, any kind of connection would have latency. To get around that, you would need to serve the data from the public server or use caching.

Comment: If you could setup a VPN service on the Public Server, have all local servers connect and they in turn will each have an IP each that could be reached from the clients if they also connect via VPN to the server. The latency should be negligible as long as the bandwidth is available. Would that work for you or is the clients random and can't be expected to connect via VPN for using the service?

Comment: The client cannot used VPN. Also I don't want to use VPN service by a third party. Or is it possible to set up our own VPN service.

Comment: You could setup your own VPN service that don't require any outside serivce or cost anything. OpenVPN is easy to use like. I've had to do the same many times for accessing testing equipment behind NAT with no public IPs. Worked like a charm with good bandwidth. But I required the clients to use a VPN.

Comment: Thanks, I will look on it.

Comment: Good place to start: _How To Set Up and Configure an OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu 20.04_ [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04)